# How do I solve for $Y$ with $Y = X^{X^Y}$ If the answer set is more than just $(x,y)=\{(0,0), (1,1)\},$ is it graphable?

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions

I remember this question from 40 years ago, and I never found a solution on my own.

If  $Y = X ^ {X ^ Y}$:

When I attempt to reduce this, it always involves both an $X$ and $Y$ on both LHS and RHS of the equation.

I'm assuming that either
1. This is done via complex numbers
or
2. This cannot be easily solved (it reminds me of a discussion of $x^y=y^x$).

Answer (score 1):

You can make $X$ the subject of the formula using the Lambert function.

Take logs and multiply by $Y$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y \ln Y = X^Y \ln X^Y. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $u= \ln X^Y $ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y \ln Y = u e^u 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now recall the Lambert $W$ function is defined by $we^w=z$ gives $w=W(z)$. So we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln X^Y   =  W(Y \ln Y) \\
X= e^{W(Y \ln Y)/Y}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember enough math to see the equation x= in only terms of e, ln(), and y.  Trying to spray down a dried up set of neurons with caffeine....